# Generalization of a 1D unitary representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, group-cohomology

Probably a very naive question, but I'd be grateful for any input. Consider 1D representations of finite group $G$: $\chi(g) \chi(h) = \chi(g h)$ with $\chi(g)\in \text{U}(1)$, and $\chi(1)=1$. The set of all such $\chi$ is also denoted $H^1(G,\text{U}(1))$.

Suppose $G$ comes with a homomorphism $\alpha: G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2= \{1,-1\}$. I've encountered (in a physics context) class functions obeying condition $ \chi(g h) =\chi(g)^{\alpha(h)} \chi(h)^{\alpha(g)}$ and with $\chi(g)\in \text{U}(1)$, and $\chi(1)=1$. My question is: Given a $G$ and fixing an $\alpha$, is there a succinct name for the set of all such $\chi$? Could you recommend some references?

Comment: $H^1 (G, U(1))$ is not a *notation* for this set of $\chi$. If you make $G$ act trivially on $U(1)$ then the first cohomology group $H^1 (G,U(1))$ coincides with ${\rm Hom}_{{\rm Group}} (G, U(1))$.

Comment: Thanks!  To clarify, we're agreed that if I specify that $G$ acts trivially on $U(1)$, then $H^1(G,U(1))$ is in 1:1 correspondence with the 1D unitary representations of G? Any ideas on the main part of the question?

Comment: I'm curious, what is the physics context in which such an object appears? If you replaced the condition with $\chi(gh) = \chi(g) \chi(h)^{\alpha(g)}$ it would correspond to $H^1(G, U(1))$ with non-trivial action of $G$ on $U(1)$ specified by $\alpha$ (and, in physics, would describe the eigenvalue of a state under a partially anti-unitary representation of $G$.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I recognize the formula you wrote down from the definition of $H^{1}(G,U(1)_{T})$ in Wen's papers. But I'm resolutely not looking at this formula. As for the physics context, this probably isn't the place to discuss it -- let me contact you over email.